# stop magento image zoom from loading on parse (even when successfully "turned off")

Tags: magento

stop image zoom from loading on parse (even when successfully "turned off")

http://pro-tools-training.com/magentotest2/index.php/doc/mix-it-like-a-record.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is going on there, but you can always hack the template to prevent it from displaying something by wrapping the code with `<?php /*  */?>` comments or you can add the following css:

```
.zoom-notice, .zoom { display: none }
```

Comment: 1. what phtml file would you hack if you wer doing it <?php /* */?>

Comment: 2. what css file would you place that code in to prevent display?  .zoom-notice, .zoom { display: none }

Comment: the zoom code to comment out is in /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml and the css file is whatever css file you use.  The css would be in /skin/frontend/default/default/css

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading a larger image, the image doesn't appear to need to be "zoomed" since its below the width and height, the controls then disappear.  To verify, try changing your design temporarily to the default template to ensure its not anything wrong with your template also.